# Entity Framework Relationship Fix-up Failure

Tags: entity-framework

For the below code, the expected behavior of EF is to commit order and the `orderItem` with `orderID=100` and as far as I know, this auto assignment of the field `orderID` is known as relatinship fix-up. So, we do not have to provide the `orderID` field for the `orderItem` to be added.

```
        Entities ctx = new Entities();

        Order order = new Order()
        {
            ID = 100,
            name = "abc"
        };

        // ID field of OrderItem is auto-increment and the primary field
        //OrderItem is a navigation property of Order through the orderID field
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem ()
        {
            name = "oi_abc"
        };
        order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);

        ctx.Orders.Add(order);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This piece of sample code works as expected. But the problem is, a similar piece of code in our project fails to do proper relationship fix-up. (I know it would be best if I could provide the whole code but it is impossible due to other complexities of the code and database and also due to our company policy.)

The code in our project simply sets `orderID` as 0 during commit.

Some important things to note:

1. We do not disable tracking changes of the context anywhere
2. Setting orderID manually works but it is not desired for us
3. If we have the `ctx.Orders.Add(order);` line right after creating the `order` object, then it work as expected.

Do you have any guesses as to why such a failure would happen, given the circumstances above?

Comment: If you can't show the actual failing code, could you instead share a minimum reproduction of the issue?

Do you get an exception?

Your statement ```The code in our project simply sets orderID as 0 during commit. ``` is telling. I *believe* the EF generated proxies can tell the difference between an uninitiated 0 value and one that has been explicitly set. If it has seen you set the Id, it will assume you have set it to a value you know is good and will therefore save it with that value instead of running fixup.

Am not in a position to test this theory currently so it is just a guess.

Comment: relationship fixup only works for entries that are both (all) in the context. I would expect your order object is neither loaded nor attached within the processing context. If this is the case, I would advise to attach the order object (unchanged is fine)